# what is the best way to use ansible for reading hosts ip address and use it later?

Tags: ansible

i have 3 hosts, first one is the controller and the other two are used as lamp. i have to write a playbook in ansible which finds the ip address of each host and use it later in the same ansible playbook for settings.
   basically i want to save it in a variable and use it for later.

Here is how i read it

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  tasks:
    - debug: var=ansible_all_ipv4_addresses
    - debug: var=ansible_default_ipv4.address
```

This is where i want to use it:

```
---
- hosts: laborator
  become: yes
  become_user: root

  tasks:
    - name: Create directory for php page
      file:
        path: /var/www/html/virtual1
        state: directory
        owner: apache
        group: apache
        mode: 0775
        recurse: yes
    - name: ensure file exists
      copy:
        content: ""
        dest: /var/www/html/virtual1/info.php
        owner: apache
        group: apache
        force: no
        mode: 0555
    - name: Add a string to the new file
      lineinfile: dest=/var/www/html/virtual1/info.php
                regexp='^'
                line='<?php phpinfo(); ?>'
                state=present
    - name: Change file permissions
      file:
        path: /var/www/virtual1/info.php
        owner: apache
        group: apache
        mode: 0644
    - name: Set some kernel parameters
      lineinfile:
        path: /etc/hosts
        regexp: '^'
        line: '192.168.115.198 laborator1'  <<<-here*****
```

You can see the line where i need the ip. I'm new to ansible this is my second day, please point me into the right direction.

thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the `gather_fact: yes` in your play (it's the default value unless you disabled in on your [`gathering` config](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/intro_configuration.html#gathering)), you will be able to access the `ansible_default_ipv4.address` value for the current host.
If you want to access for another host (on which there was a gather_fact), you can use `hostvars[INVENTORY_HOSTNAME].ansible_default_ipv4.address`.
There is also `ansible_ethX.ipv4.address` for each interface.

You can see all the available variables by using the [`setup` module](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/setup_module.html)

```
ansible all -m setup
```

Variables doc: http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_variables.html#magic-variables-and-how-to-access-information-about-other-hosts

In your case, it could be:

```
- name: Put IP of each laborator hosts in /etc/hosts
  lineinfile:
    path: /etc/hosts
    regexp: '^'
    line: '{{ hostvars[item].ansible_default_ipv4.address }} {{ hostvars[item].ansible_hostname }}'
  with_items: '{{ groups.laborator }}'
```